# Facebook SDK 9.0 not installed with cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

As per the new release of Facebook SDK, all the old SDK is deprecated. But when I tried to update the Facebook SDK through a cocoa pod in my running objective c project then it is not updating to version 9.0, it only downloading the 8.2.0, which is depreciated as per the attached link.

Please let me know if there is any technical issue or what, why it's not updating.

Regards

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/19/introducing-facebook-platform-sdk-version-9/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=fb4d-newsletter-january21&utm_campaign=organic&utm_offering=developer-platform&utm_product=platform&utm_content=body-button-platform-sdk&utm_location=2

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase platform number in your Podfile. For example: **platform :ios, '14.0'**

Comment: I have done that but it not worked. It's still load 8.2.0